# html table and div's

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the following problem: I have a table with a fixed width and height, which should be in the middle.

The right of it should be **div**, with a width from the right edge of the table to the left edge of the browser, but it is necessary that in this **div** image was cropped on the right (so that only the left side, the size of **div**)

On the left side of the table you need the same thing in reverse, as well as lower

Here's what it looks like - http://db.tt/bZU8Z9SJ

How can you do?

Comment: You do know that developing websites with tables is a crime?

Comment: @kor - You do know that comments like that are totally nonconstructive?

Comment: @koen, yes, but I cut this table with Photoshop)

Comment: @Lix So are websites in tables.

Comment: @Koen. - total BS both in practise and in theory. Some data _is_ tabular data, and is appropriate to be displayed in a table. Such unqualified statements are less than useful, unless a person is trying to ascertain the value of anything further said by the person that asserts them.

Comment: @Koen: well my site has a lot of tabular data and the data is displayed using divs. But beyond tabular data, I think using tables for layout is a terrible idea.

Comment: @enhzflep I don't say tables are bad, at least not for data, but the question explains that they're needed for layout purposes. And that era is long gone.

Comment: @Koen. bs, bs, BS. You said, and I quote: "you know that developing websites with tables is a crime" - That's exactly what you said. Are you telling me that some crimes involve doing something that isn't 'bad'? Perhaps english isn't your first language? It certainly seems that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, to give you some more of an answer, make a basic layout with divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="table"> <!-- Your table here --> </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

And add some CSS:

```
#table{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
}

#left{
    float: left;
    background: #3f3;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: right;
}

#right{
    float: left;
    background: #f3f;
    width: 25%;
    height: 200px;
    background-position: left;
}
```

**Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ycS2N/**

Comment: and in case our table's width is need to be dynamic? (40-50-60% depending on something)